# accessing rails application on mac from another device

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing a ruby on rails application on my computer, and I am trying to access it from another device (iPhone, iPad), to check some functionality.

How can I configure my computer to allow serving web pages to external devices on my local network (I am still in development mode).

Comment: Do you want to access it in development mode? Using port `3000`?

Comment: yes, in development mode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default `rails server` command listens to `localhost` (Rails 4.2 and above). Start rails server using binding flag to change this behavior:

```
rails server -b 0.0.0.0
# or
rails server --bind 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Without any configuration on machines, the Rails app is accessible within the local network by specifying the IP address of your machine that hosts the Rails app in development environment.

For example, the machine that hosts the Rails app has a local IP of 192.168.1.103 and it's hosted in port 3000, your iPhone or iPad that connects to the same local network can access the Rails app by typing 192.168.1.103:3000 in the browser of the device.

If this doesn't work, normally I will use a network tunnelling service called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), that creates a temporary subdomain as an alias of your dev Rails app that's accessible publicly through internet.

Comment: it is not accessible by typing just the url

Answer (score 1):

For my future self, combining info from nayjaw & dimakura

### Testing with an iPad

Start server

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
```

Go to `System Preferences | Network` settings to find your internal IP. For example:

> Wi-Fi 2 is connected to Fios-vLC9B and has the IP address 192.168.1.154

On iPad, get to your Rails app as follows:

```
192.168.1.154:3000/
```